# Linq, поиск подстроки (или несколько элементов подряд удовлетворяющих условию)

Tags: c#, массивы, linq

Если имеется какая-то строка, как в ней с помощью linq найти такую подстроку, где например две буквы подряд стоят не в алфавитном порядке?
То есть задача: получить массив строк (пар букв), которые стояли в этой строке не в алфавитном порядке
(для массива чисел можно придумать аналогичное что-то вроде взаимно простых подряд)

Или если усложнить: найти и поместить в список все подряд идущие одинаковые элементы.

Не получается придумать как реализовать "пропуск" тех элементов, которые уже обработаны

Как найти все нечетные числа ясно, `Where(IsPrime)`, функция применяется одиночно ко всем элементам.

---

По поводу задачи на нахождения всех подпоследовательностей

IN:string str = "aaabbcddddeeaa";
OUT: {"aaa", "bb", "dddd", "ee", "aa"}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Возьмём Enumerable.Range от 0 до длины массива/строки. Это будут индексы наших элементов.
2. Выберем индексы, наложение которых на наш массив удовлетворяет требуемому условию.
3. Получим необходимый результат.

Для примера со строкой:

```
var line = "abcdfebgijhsntg";
var result = Enumerable.Range(0, line.Length - 2)
                       .Where(x => line[x] > line[x + 1])
                       .Select(x => new string(new[] { line[x], line[x+1]})).ToList();
```

Comment: Отличная идея для двух/трех элементов, спасибо. Но доработать ее до последовательности неизвестного размера у меня не выходит. Хотя и можно поставить костыль и в блок `try` для `Range(0, line.Length)` чтобы индекс не кидал ошибку, но как то это не очень

Comment: Ну, можно добавить условие на `line.length<2` с выводом ошибки/выбрасыванием исключения. Потому что для массива из одного элемента алгоритм неприменим. Проверка параметров на валидность - это вполне нормально

Comment: Извиняюсь, стоило уточнить: "последовательность неизвестного размера" - это последовательность подряд идущих одинаковых элементов в данной строке

Comment: Ну, тогда `2` заменяем на `n`, а сравнение и формирование подстроки выносим в отдельные функции

Comment: Тоже об этом думала, но у нас появляется сложность то что проходит от `0` до `length-n-1`, а повторяющееся элементы могут быть и после `length-n-1`-ого  значения

Comment: Почему `length-n-1`? просто `length-n`. Строка, скажем, 7 символов, длина подстроки 3 - смотрим символы с 0 по 4. Первая подстрока будет 0-3, последняя - 4-6. Если нужно, скажем,  при n=4 учитывать "хвосты" длиной 3 или 2 - то это нужно обработать в методах сравнения и вывода.

Comment: Нельзя сделать привязку к длине подстроки, она может быть разная. И их может быть несколько, от одной в длину всей строки и больше. В вопросе добавила уточнение; IN/OUT параметры